# Python script adding same data over and over when run from ArcToolbox?

Tags: arcpy, merge, arctoolbox

I'm fairly new to python scripting.

I've written a script that runs fine from PythonWin or the ArcMap Python window, but is having issues when I run it from ArcToolbox.

The script adds a feature dataset to a geodatabases and then takes a group of fcs (all named S_FEP from multiple geodatabases) and merges them into a single fc in that feature dataset. It then moves on and creates another feature dataset and merges another group of S_FEP fcs.

When it is run from ArcToolbox the subsequent feature datasets get created, but the first set of S_FEP fcs are merged and put in the new feature datasets instead of a new group of fcs. This only happens when running it from ArcToolbox.

```
# Import Modules
print "Importing Modules: arcpy, os & fnmatch"
arcpy.AddMessage("Importing Modules")
import arcpy
import os
import fnmatch

# Set Top Level Variables
topDir = r"C:\Test\August"
#topDir = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

MonthYear = "082016" 
#MonthYear = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

workingFldr = "FEP_XS_Working"

# Set Top Environment
arcpy.env.workspace = topDir
print "Environment set to:", topDir
arcpy.AddMessage("Environment Set")

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
print "Overwrite Outputs = True"
arcpy.AddMessage("Overwrite Outputs = True")

# Create FEP_XS_Working Folder in topDir
arcpy.CreateFolder_management(topDir, workingFldr)
print "Created FEP_XS_Working Folder"
arcpy.AddMessage("Created FEP_XS_Working Folder")

# Create IDNR_FEP_XS_MonthYear.gdb in FEP_XS_Working folder
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(os.path.join(topDir,os.path.basename(workingFldr)), "IDNR_FEP_XS_" + MonthYear + ".gdb")
workDB = os.path.join(topDir, os.path.basename(workingFldr),"IDNR_FEP_XS_" + MonthYear + ".gdb")
print "Created Database:", workDB
arcpy.AddMessage("Created Database")

# List folders in topDir
for basinfolder in os.listdir(topDir):
    if basinfolder.startswith('0'):
        print "Found Basin:", basinfolder
        arcpy.AddMessage("Found Basin")

        # Create Feature Dataset
        cs = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 UTM Zone 16N')
        arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(workDB, "HUC10_"+basinfolder, cs)
        featureDS = os.path.join(workDB, "HUC10_"+os.path.basename(basinfolder))
        print "Created Feature Dataset:", featureDS
        arcpy.AddMessage("Created Feature Dataset")

        # Create List of S_FEP Layers and Create Variable for their Projections
        FEPMergeLst = []
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(topDir):
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'S_FEP'):
                FEPMergeLst.append(os.path.join(dirpath,filename))


        # Merge all FEP layers into a single layer
        if FEPMergeLst:
            outDir = featureDS
            outNm = "Flood_Elevation_Pts_DRN_Water_"+os.path.basename(basinfolder)

            outLyr = os.path.join(outDir, os.path.basename(outNm))
            print "outLyr =", outLyr

            arcpy.Merge_management(FEPMergeLst, outLyr)
            print "Completed S_FEP Merge"
            arcpy.AddMessage("Completed S_FEP Merge")
```

Comment: A few suggestions and my diagnostic on this. First, you can create a function/def in Python to print your messages (which is the overall idea behind OOP) instead of repeating print and AddMessage. Second, instead of getting folder/file path through os module, you can use Result object of arcpy. Basically, `featureDS = arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(workDB, "HUC10_"+basinfolder, cs)[0]` will give you exactly what the following `os.path.join` gives. I did not test your code but think this might be the culprit.

Comment: Lastly, you may try to delete feature dataset before creating, such as `arcpy.Delete_management(os.path.join(workDB, "HUC10_"+os.path.basename(basinfolder)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `walk` you are walking through **all** workspaces in `topDir` and not just the workspaces in the current `basinfolder`.  As a result it is finding all the feature classes and merging them into one, not just the ones in the specified `basinfolder`.

To stop it from merging all feature classes, you need to change the part `for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(topDir)` to the following:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(os.path.join(topDir, basinfolder)):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'S_FEP'):
        FEPMergeLst.append(os.path.join(dirpath,filename))
```

Comment: Midavalo, thanks for the suggestion. I'll give a try today!